# Disable some category In-Place Editor (IPE)

Tags: 8, users, panels

I'm working with a Lightning distribution of Drupal 8. I need to show to the editor, for example, only the **Create content**tab under **Manage content** tab in panelizer. I'm not finding anything to do this. I tried with the permissions or looking at the panelizer settings, but nothing worked.
So, I need to remove all the Chaos Tools, Devel, Forms etc tabs.

Comment: Probably https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/284395/10157 would help.